# adding two phone agendas together

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I got this problem where I need to create a phone agenda where every name coresponds to a phone number. I decided to create this as a 2 dimensional string array.

But what I do not know how to do is:

I need to create 2 agendas(created in main) and then add them together to create one big agenda that contains the members of `ag1` and `ag2`. Please help me create the method that does that.

L.E: I'm learning "operator overloading" in school, maybe it has something to do with this.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

class Agenda{
    string date[20][20];
public:
    Agenda();
    void afisare();
};

Agenda::Agenda(){
    int i, j, n;

    cout << "Numarul de intrari: ";
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            cout << "Date[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
            fflush(stdin);
            getline(cin, date[i][j]);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}

void Agenda::afisare(){
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++){
            cout << "Date[" << i << "][" << j << "] = ";
            cout << date[i][j] << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void main(){
    Agenda ag1;
    cout << "-----AGENDA 1-----" << endl;
    ag1.afisare();

    Agenda ag2;
    cout << "-----AGENDA 2-----" << endl;
    ag2.afisare();
}
```

Comment: max. 20 names and 20 numbers.

Comment: Hi Olar Andrei, I see you've posted an answer to try to get your question more attention. I'll get back to that. Your question might have few views, and therefore answers, because the subject, "*adding two phone agendas together*" makes it seem like you've not abstracted your problem sufficiently. If it was something more programming-sounding, like "*how do I merge information from these two classes*", or even something like "*array created from two arrays*" you might have better luck. Regarding your answer, you shouldn't post a comment as an answer to 'bump' a question up for attention.

Comment: @olarandrei what you have is 20 columns and 20 rows -- 400 entries.  You want 40 entries.